# Prefering functions in tidyverse over other loaded packages

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to prefer a function (select) from the dplyr package. I loaded a package that depends on MASS package that masks select function. Is there an alternative way to prefer select from the dplyr package other than the convention `dplyr::select()`?

Comment: Load `MASS` first, then `dplyr`. The latest to load should mask the earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to worry aboutpackage loading order, as you see in @benson23 answer, this is one way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)
select <- dplyr::select
```

Another way is using conflicted package:

```
library(conflicted)
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)
conflict_prefer("select", "dplyr")
```

At last, if you use want to use tidymodels meta-package (includes dplyr), you can do this too:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(MASS)
tidymodels_prefer()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a few options for this:

1. Load your other packages first, and at last, load `tidyverse` or `dplyr`
2. At the very beginning of your script, do

```
select <- dplyr::select
```

You can combine the above two options in your `.Rprofile` file, so that every time you launch R, the above actions will be executed.